# Determine all natural number $x, y, z$ for which the equation $4x^2+45y^2+9z^2-12xy-36yz=25$ is valid and where the $x<y<z.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Since, Only Natural Numbers Solution are needed, So I thought this as a Diophantine Equation, But was unable to handle, 2nd Degrees 3 variable Diophantine Equation.

I Tried to manipulate this Equation as Sum of Squares But I was unsuccessful in doing so,
$(2x -7y +3z)^2+16xy-15yz-12xz-4y^2=25$

Can anyone think of some approach ?

**Note:** *Through Online Diophantine Editor, I Found out that it has about 333 integer solutions, But I have a constraint of Natural Numbers and $x<y<z$*

Comment: Hint: the LHS$=(2x-3y)^2+(3z-6y)^2$.

Comment: Are you sure you got $333$ solutions because $25=0^2+(\pm 5)^2=(\pm 3)^2+(\pm 4)^2$.

Comment: https://www.hackmath.net/en/calculator/integer-diophantine-equations-solver
This was the site,I checked

Comment: Well as you can see with the argument I have given, it cannot have that many solutions.

Comment: I Find your Solution, more valid and Logical, Thanks  a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this until the moment, maybe I'm missing something but I think this can help you

$$ 4x^2 + 45y^2+9z^2-12xy-36yz = 25 $$
$$ 4(x^2-3xy +9y²) +9(y²-4yz+z²) = 25 $$

Let's rename the terms $x² -3xy+9y²$ and $y^2-4yz+z²$ as $s$ and $t$. We know that as x, y and z must be naturals, then $s$ and $t$ must be integers. So you can start by finding all integers that solve the equation $4s + 9t = 25$. A couple comes to mind, $s = 4$ and $t = 1$.

I know this isn't a full solution but maybe it can help you

Comment: Surprised by the up votes for this as I don't see how your solution can be helpful. Perhaps can you elaborate on how to solve for $x,y$ from $x^2-3xy+9y^2=s$?

Comment: I don't know either, just hoped this will help the guy to go one step closer to the solution

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more friendly than the suggestion of @Anurag:

Treat the quadratic of $x,y,z$ as a quadratic of $x$ only, then get
$$x=\frac{1}{2}[3y \pm \sqrt{25-36y^2-9z^2+36yz}]\implies 2x=3y\pm\sqrt{25-(6y-3z)^2}$$
For the radical to be a perfect square there are three possibilities $(6y-3z)=0,\pm 3, \pm 4,\pm 5.$ You may carry it over now.

Comment: Actually $6y-3z=\pm 5$ is also a possibility. This is same as what I have already suggested in the comments. By the way solving a quadratic is equivalent to completing the squares so not sure how is this "more friendly" :-)

Comment: But making perfect square requires trails but this method is more general even if perfect squares are not possible. Students shpuld be encouraged to go for it.

Comment: I am all for students being encouraged to explore all possible methods. But I have to politely disagree with you on this being a "more general" method. If this was a cubic or higher degree in say $x$, your method of isolating $x$ will not be fruitful in general and in many cases you won't be even able to solve for $x$ in terms of other variables. Now if the equation is of degree $2$, then solving for $x$ is akin to completion of squares only and the moment you talk about discriminant being a perfect square etc., you are pretty much back to completion of squares or some sort of Pell's equation.

Comment: @Amurag in order to foind integer solutions to $x^2+y^2-xy-x-y=1$ what will you do?

Comment: Not sure why you asked me this question but I would simply write this as $$(x-y)^2+(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=4.$$ Hope this helps you prove some point that I might be overlooking :-)

Comment: I think it will be obvious with this representation that it can have no integer solutions because the only way to split $4$ as sum of three squares would be to write it as $4=0^2+0^2+(\pm 2)^2$.